# CSS - Clearfix not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get clearfix to work on my website however i can't get it to work correctly. I'm trying to use clearfix on the header so the image and background beneth are positioned correctly.

Here is the code i've used.

Thank you!

// CSS

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */

#logo {
    display:block;
    padding-top: 26px;
    float:left;

}

#hero {

 background:#eae8e8;  

}

/*-----------------------
Navigation
------------------------*/

nav ul {
 margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none; /* gets rid of bullet points */
    float:right;
/* --------------------------

Global styles
```

HTML

```
<header> <!-- html 5 -->

                <div class="container clearfix">

                <div id="logo">

                <a href="/" title="return to home" id="logo"> <!-- title adds tooltips -->
                <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
                </a>
                </div>
                <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>  
                </ul>
                </nav>
            </div> <!-- container div -->

                <div id ="hero">

                <img src="hero.jpg" alt="hero image" id="hero-image">

                </div> <!-- end hero div-->

            </header>
```

Comment: You need to show us some more of your CSS: you haven't actually shown any element being set to `float`, so there's nothing to clear. Perhaps you could test your example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: ive added some more CSS, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an empty class with the clearfix class (without :after) just after the div you want to clear.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Zbsd/8/)

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

See if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you! Realised i missed out a } in the CSS, which was causing issues, but used your method and works.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, without using `:before` you can use shorter, simplier `overflow: hidden` on `.container`.

You will remember that easier than your solution with before and many lines of code.